# Cannot find the correct CSS selector for webscraping

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I'm trying to scrape some tv ratings from IMDb but am unable to find the correct CSS selector. I've tried dozens of alternatives, and have attempted to use the CSS Selector Gadget but R is returning a `{xml_nodeset (0)}` value.

This is my code as it is:

```
require(rvest)

read_html('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562992/?ref_=ttep_ep1') %>% 
  html_nodes('a.ipc-button ipc-button--single-padding ipc-button--center-align-content ipc-button--default-height ipc-button--core-baseAlt ipc-button--theme-baseAlt ipc-button--on-textPrimary ipc-text-button RatingBarButtonBase__Button-sc-15v8ssr-2 jjcqHZ')
```

What I want to do is extract the href that is embedded in the rating on the top left of the page. See the image below where i've highlighted the href i'm looking to extract in the developer view CSS.

Could someone help me figure out the right selector?

[image]

Comment: Try 'div[class^=hero-rating-bar] > a[class^=ipc-button]' if you want to go down CSS route, this uses partial selecting, so the ^ means class starting with. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well complete the set of recommendations.

---

You don't need to worry about dynamic classes. Use a stable class from the multi-value class as parent then child combinate to get the child `a` tag:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562992/?ref_=ttep_ep1"  
link <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_element(".rating-bar__base-button > a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  url_absolute(url)
```

---

Or, as IMDb has a consistent approach to these things, avoid making a request and simply do a substitution on the query string part of the url. You could encapsulate this into a ratings function.

```
url <- "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562992/?ref_=ttep_ep1"
link <- gsub("(\\?ref_=.*)", "ratings/?ref_=tt_ov_rt", url)
```

Comment: This is educational. Thanks. I was looking to get the href embedded in the rating, not the actual rating though. So i've accepted Ronak's answer

Comment: That's great, and definitely simpler. How could I not find this CSS on my own though?? I spent hours looking. And yeah, a few hours after posting my question I realized I could just change the end of the URL (i'm doing a lot of these so avoiding the requests is a real advantage). I ended up with: `all_links %>% mutate(ratings_link = str_sub(.$link, 1, str_locate(.$link, "\\?")[,1]-2), ratings_link = paste0('https://www.imdb.com', ratings_link, '/ratings/?ref_=tt_ov_rt'))`

Comment: Relying on tools to give you css selectors, or right clicking inspect, are great starting points. There is no substitute for practice. Tooling usually gives you something overly complex. Learning tricks like how to spot a stable'ish class, within a multi-valued class,  how to use partial attribute values, and [how to construct your own relationships](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) takes practice. See my profile page for some links to css selector resources.

Comment: Thanks QHarr. These look like some good resources -- i'll definitely dig into them

Answer (score 2):

Inspect element, then right-click and copy>copy selector

Comment: This is a good tip, but it hasn't solved my problem. Exact code I ran: `html_nodes('#__next > main > div > section.ipc-page-background.ipc-page-background--base.TitlePage__StyledPageBackground-wzlr49-0.dDUGgO > section > div:nth-child(4) > section > section > div.TitleBlock__Container-sc-1nlhx7j-0.hglRHk > div.RatingBar__RatingContainer-sc-85l9wd-0.hNqCJh.TitleBlock__HideableRatingBar-sc-1nlhx7j-4.bhTVMj > div > div:nth-child(1) > a > div > div > div.AggregateRatingButton__ContentWrap-sc-1ll29m0-0.hmJkIS > div.AggregateRatingButton__TotalRatingAmount-sc-1ll29m0-3.jkCVKJ')`

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is because of the IDs at the end of some classes like "jjcqHZ" ,"15v8ssr".
Many frontend framework change these IDs per refresh.
Try to select element without these classes.

Comment: Hmm interesting. This returns the same `xml_nodeset(0)` value that I saw before though. Exact code I ran: `read_html('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562992/?ref_=ttep_ep1') %>% 
  html_nodes('a.ipc-button ipc-button--single-padding ipc-button--center-align-content ipc-button--default-height ipc-button--core-baseAlt ipc-button--theme-baseAlt ipc-button--on-textPrimary ipc-text-button RatingBarButtonBase__Button-sc')`

Answer (score 1):

I would actually use XPaths as classes are very dynamic and not very reliable in this instance.

```
<div>foobar</div>
```

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

console.log(getElementByXpath("//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]") );
```

[image: Here is an example of comparisons between CSS vs Xpaths]

Comment: This seems promising and is a great tip. The code you've shared above though is way beyond me. This is what I ran: `read_html('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562992/?ref_=ttep_ep1') %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/section[1]/section/div[3]/section/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')` but unfortunately when I then try to extract the `href` by piping the above into `html_attr('href')` it returns a `NA` value

Comment: I am not familiar with R but if it's similar to python you could parse the html into a package like beautifulsoup and then extract the href that way? I am avoiding regular expressions here as that is not full proof.

Comment: Ok fair! I am using `rvest` which is the R equivalent as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath -

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562992/?ref_=ttep_ep1'

url %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_element(xpath = '//*[@aria-label="View User Ratings"]') %>%
  #For older version of rvest use `html_node`
  #html_node(xpath = '//*[@aria-label="View User Ratings"]') %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  paste0('https://www.imdb.com', .)

#[1] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562992/ratings/?ref_=tt_ov_rt"
```